# Error in closing files

Tags: python

I'm running Python 2.6.5 and part of my code involves opening and reading a text file. The problem is the command I'd expect to use to close the file isn't working, where I get an error reading:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

This stems from:

```
# Open header and data files to create a dictionary
header = open("pathToHeader","rU")
data = open(os.path.join(someFilePath,fileName),"rU")

# Create the dictionary whose contents can be called by columns[header]
f = chain(h,data)
reader = csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=h.read().strip('\n').split(','),delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    for (header,variable) in row.items():
        columns[header].append(str(variable))


# Close the two files
header.close()
data.close()
```

From what I've looked up so far, this is the correct command to close a file. Is it because I'm assigning the open command to a variable why I'm having trouble? Does the file close itself once I've created the dictionary?

Comment: For the future, consider using python's [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) statement

Comment: Is `h` the same object as `header` in this code? If not, what is `header` used for and where is `h` opened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `close()` on a string, not a file object, because you have *re-used* the name `header`:

```
for (header,variable) in row.items():
```

Best practice is to use file objects in a `with` statement, as context managers. That way they are closed automatically, regardless of how the block ended:

```
with open("pathToHeader","rU") as header:
    fieldnames = h.read().strip('\n').split(',')

data_file = os.path.join(someFilePath, fileName)
with open(data_file, "rU") as data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data, fieldnames)
    for row in reader:
        for key, variable in row.items():
            columns[key].append(variable)
```

I've refactored your code a little in the process. Note that there is little point in chaining `header` before `data` if you are going to read all of `header` *anyway*.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrote header in your inner `for` loop. Rename it.

Answer (score 1):

You've redefined the variable `header` within the for loop.